# Add "tag categories"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, tags, tag-hierarchy

Currently questions are added in a rapid pace to SO, so that new questions disappear very quickly from the homepage. It I want to see questions from my areas of interest I can do either:

- Go to the tagged/my tags page, but then I will see the questions only according to the votes
- Supply a list of tags "x or y or z", but it seems the list is limited to 15 or 20 tags.

What I suggest is to have categories as grouping of tags - the .net category , java category , web development category , etc. It can also help new users to locate questions from their area of expertise they can answer. We can decide that a category can contain between 5 and 20  tags in order no to have too narrow or too broad categories (numbers were given just for the sake of argument)

Comment: Like tag categories?

Comment: pretty much, yes, but a tag can be in several zones

Comment: Tagged tags​​​.

Comment: I heard you liked tags, so we added tags to your tags so you can tag tags. Tags.

Comment: @smeagol Maybe more like, "Yo dawg, we heard you like tags, so we added tags to your tags so you can tag while you're tagging."

Comment: @random: I'm not well versed in my own language's slangs, let alone foreign slangs :) Anyway, you got the point ;)

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like you are looking for something oddly similar to a tag hierarchy without the full blown tree structure. Tree-structure tagging has been shot down by the team numerous times and they have made it pretty evident that they don't want to go in that direction.

Your suggestion sounds like it would attempt to lead in that direction and I don't necessarily think it is for the best.

Comment: I don't think that a tag hierarchy is a good thing, especially when each tag can be in several categories. However, I don't think that going to the other extreme and say "no, flat hierarchy is the one and only way" is good as well.