# Should we categorize / group site tags with similar intent, and how?

Tags: discussion, tags, stack-exchange, tag-synonyms

I desperately want to avoid asking "do we need tag tags".  Many of the SE sites have tag pages inundated with titles; most notably [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) and to a lesser extent [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com), [Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and [RPGs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/).

I am of the opinion that having titles for tags on these sites is 100% necessary and relevant and allows proper categorization of related questions.

Unfortunately, as evidenced by the tag pages of these sites, having titles obfuscates more general tags of other relevance, such as utility tags *(using Movies & TV as an example: [plot-explanation](/questions/tagged/plot-explanation), [identify-this-movie](/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie), [specific-scene](/questions/tagged/specific-scene), [film-techniques](/questions/tagged/film-techniques), etc.)*, title tags *(again, M&TV: [dark-knight-rises](/questions/tagged/dark-knight-rises), [forrest-gump](/questions/tagged/forrest-gump), etc.)*, and possibly site-specific categorized tags *(M&TV; category would be "genre": [western](/questions/tagged/western), [science-fiction](/questions/tagged/science-fiction), etc.)*.  Even tag aliases could be categorized as such, if they aren't already.  Every SE Meta already does this to some extent with the "required" tags.

While the expected practice is for the tag pages of these sites to sort themselves based on usage (in Movies & TV, a lot of the common utilities **have** bubbled to the top as expected over the lesser titles, but then-again, it's still in Beta), there are other sites (notably, Arqade) where applicable tags are drowned in titles and therefore will never be found in order to be used enough to sort in the expected fashion.

Yes, I do understand it is up to each community's participants to manage their tags, but even general clean-up is somewhat daunting and might not prove to be effective.

**Why do I think we need this?**  Without foreknowledge or expertise, or knowing what to type out during a question, it is very tough to locate a tag you might want to use in these sites.  Tag categorization could help a user properly tag a question by suggesting categories of tags to choose from, then relevant tags.

Is tag categorization needed, and if so, how should categorization be applied; via a new built-in SE utility, an adopted practice, or other enhancement?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/root-tags-to-organize-larger-sites-with-multiple-categories http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24718/add-tag-categories

Comment: Not the tree-based one, but the root one, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that tag categorization is necessary and can be applied with a new functional enhancement using new (non-existing) functionality, "tag categorization" tags.

In general, a way to implement it would be to have new "category" tags (... "tag tags"), which would appear differently in the tag list page (emboldened or otherwise), which could not be applied to questions.

When you create a tag or edit a tag wiki, you add the tag to a category.  A tag can only be in one category.  If your reputation is high enough, you can create a new category during this process which would have the life-cycle of a standard tag.

Using the above examples, Movies & TV might have tag categories of "title-movie", "title-tv", "genre-related", "plot-related", and "utility".

After implementation, work would require the community to visit each tag and assign it a category, or create a category for it.  Uncategorized tags would fall under category "uncategorized-tag", the resolution of which could possibly be gamified with review badges or similar.