# Where is the organization in this website?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, stack-exchange, site-categories

##### Question Categories

Imagine a reference book with no table of contents.  Ridiculous, right?

This is an amazing reference site, and it needs to group questions in **categories**.  I see none.  Just **tags**.  There are a million different types of tags one could use.  It's a terrible way of organization - that's why almost nobody uses it solely.  If it's used as well as categories, of course, it enhances things.  But to rely on it only for finding things.....doesn't work well for most of us.

##### Site Categories

I see some groupings at https://stackexchange.com/sites#, but it's not organized properly.

- Do you have Gardening besides Travel?
- Server Fault beside Photography?

It looks like you took categories and threw them in a blender.  Is this on purpose?  I don't get it.

I see:

- Technology
- Culture / Recreation
- Life / Arts
- Science
- Business
- Professional

On the top, but within each, it's also jumbled.

Tor beside Sound Design.  Tor should be under Operating Systems or Privacy.

It's not even in alphabetical order!  Why?  Are you purposely trying to make things difficult to find?  I do not understand.

Comment: I see a lot of complaining and no solution. How exactly would you like the sites to be ordered?

Comment: Do like other sites do.  Put subjects in categories.  Because its easy to make mistakes with tags or simply use different tags than others would use.  Often you're discussing a subject that is part of a group and you would find many other subjects in that group also interesting.  And list things in the same font sizes!  Imagine reading a book where the font changes paragraph to paragraph.  What you want is for the reader to find their interest as quickly as possible.  That's my solution.  Hopefully it sounds logical.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're not that .... diligent.  When searching for answers.

Comment: as for question organization, while a nice thought, I don't think Stack Exchange was designed to be that. More like a library where each book is a specific Q&A, and the general use-flow is search problem, find Q, read A, leave (repeat as necessary). We do at least have the "Linked" sidebar section, and the "Related" sidebar section (but that one's not very useful with its current implementation).

Answer (score 15):

The sites *are* broken into categories, like so:

[image]

You can then choose a category and order the sites as you wish — including in alphabetical order:

[image]

Here are your full options:

[image]

The idea of [grouping tags together in categories](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87656/root-tags-to-organize-larger-sites-with-multiple-categories?lq=1), as I think you've suggested, has been done before (see also [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24718/add-tag-categories?lq=1)). I've heard that the idea hasn't good over incredibly well with the team, but they haven't said no to it yet.

My view on it is that yes, it could help new users browsing the site. There are a hell of a lot of tags on any given site, and when you get to the larger sites, things become even wilder. However,

1. As you become more experienced, you learn more about the tags.
2. If you start to type in a couple letters in the tag bar thingie, you'll be given a short list of tags containing that letter. So if you had a question about BLT sandwiches, you could type `sandwich` into the bar and be shown a bunch of different tags containing that word. Or, you could just type it into the search bar under the "Tags" page on the top.
3. In general, you can type the name of the main focus of your question into the tag bar thingie, and chances are good that there's a tag for that.

Comment: HDE 226868, that was a great answer.  Thank you.  I would recommend replacing the settings icon on the upper right hand corner with a Sort By box so we don't have to hunt for it. There's tons of room.  Most readers will assume that this is not available if its not in plain site like it is in almost every other website now.  If you have organization/filtering, it should be displayed in a very up front manner, not hiding behind an icon.  Many websites use different styles of icons further complicating things, so just use English for clarity.  Its not as if you don't have the space. :)

Comment: @Bob: Are you using one of the apps, or something? The main site *already* uses a drop-down box for sorting, not a settings icon.

Comment: @Bob Which icon do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I see no need for categories unless you are talking about the community/site level.

I think tags provide an extremely flexible means to classify questions on Stack Exchange sites.  Such flexibility is important to assist the very different communities that "inhabit" over 150 sites.

They are easy to add and remove from any questions tagged "incorrectly" and enable self-assembling FAQs for new users.

For example, if viewed in a browser, these are the most frequently asked questions about the [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) tag on this site: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags?sort=frequent